# Matrix Submodular Inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequalities

Given $a,b,x > 0$ I know following the submodularity property holds:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{a} - \frac{1}{a+x} \geq \frac{1}{a+b} - \frac{1}{a+b+x}
\end{align}
My question is, does this property hold for matrices? Precisely, for $A,B,X \succ 0$ is it the case that:
\begin{align}
A^{-1} - (A+X)^{-1} \succeq (A+B)^{-1} - (A+B+X)^{-1}
\end{align}
By '$\succeq$' I mean that if $A \succeq B$ then $A−B \succeq 0$, or, is positive semi-definite.

Comment: Already the version for real numbers is false -- e.g. for $a=b=x=1$ the left hand side is $1/2$, while the right hand side is $5/6$.

Comment: My apologies I meant subtraction on the right side which holds 1/2 > 1/6, will fix this now

Comment: O.k., now after your edit, the version for real numbers is correct. But which relator do you mean by $\succeq$ for matrices? -- And what entries are your matrices supposed to have?

Comment: The entries of the matrices could be any real numbers. By '$\succeq$' I mean that if $A \succeq B$ then $A - B \succeq 0$, or, is positive semi-definite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider 
$$ A = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & 1\cr},\ X = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & 0\cr},\ B = \pmatrix{1 & 1\cr 1 & 1\cr}$$
$$ \eqalign{A^{-1} &- (A+X)^{-1} = \pmatrix{1/2 & 0\cr 0 & 0\cr}\cr &\not\succeq 
(A+B)^{-1} - (A+X+B)^{-1} = \pmatrix{4/15 & -2/15 \cr -2/15 & 1/15}}$$
Yes, I know $B$ and $X$ are positive semidefinite rather than positive definite; add $\epsilon I$ for $\epsilon $ sufficiently small.

Comment: Ah very good, I see. Do you know if the above inequality  then holds instead for $A, B, X \succ I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix?

Comment: It does not.  Take any counterexample with $A, B, X$ positive definite and scale appropriately.

Comment: I'm confused, for your example above if we define $A_2 = A + I$ and $B_2 = B + (1+\epsilon)I$ and $X_2 = X + (1+\epsilon)I$ then the inequality does hold: $A_2^{-1} - (A_2 + X_2)^{-1} \succeq (A_2 + B_2)^{-1} - (A_2 + B_2 + X_2)^{-1}$. I do not have a proof (certainly) but I could not find an epsilon for which this did not hold.

Comment: Take $A = I$, $X(\epsilon) = \pmatrix{1+\epsilon & 0\cr 0 & \epsilon\cr}$, $B(\epsilon) = \pmatrix{1+\epsilon & 1\cr 1 & 1+\epsilon\cr}$.  Your inequality fails for some $\epsilon > 1/10$, say, and 
$A, B(\epsilon), X(\epsilon) \succeq \epsilon I$.  So $10A, 10B(\epsilon), 10X(\epsilon) \succ I$, and the inequality fails for them.

Comment: Ah yes! Excellent! Thank you kindly.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, does it hold for the trace? In your example seems to hold.